# How to create method Update user in angularjs and asp.net webAPI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a crud for user, functions add and delete works but the edit method does not work, here is my code. this error

```
---: Failed to load http://localhost:14539/api/Users: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code used :

```
$scope.userEdit = function () {
    console.log('edit');
    var idsForEdit = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.listeOfUsers, function (item,$uibModalInstance, index) {
        console.log($scope.listeOfUsers);
        if (item.checked) {
            console.log(item.checked);
            console.log(item);
           // idsForEdit.edit(item);
            $scope.registration.Email=item.Email;
            $scope.registration.Password=item.PasswordHash;
            $scope.registration.Users_Role=item.Role;
            $scope.registration.Site=item.Site;
            $scope.ok = function () {
                console.log("ok");
                $scope.user=item;
                console.log($scope.user);

                User.Update({
                        id: item.Id
                    }, function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log("ok");
                        SweetAlert.swal({
                            title: "Opération effectuée avec succès!",
                            text: "Click pour quitter!",
                            type: "success"
                        });
                        $state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {
                            reload: true,
                            inherit: false,
                            notify: true
                        });
                        $uibModalInstance.close();
                    },
                    function (err) {
                    });


                console.log($scope.user);

            };
        }
    });
    //$scope.isEditDirty==true;
};
```

and this user.controller:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
// [HttpPut]
[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
public IHttpActionResult PutUsers(string id, Users users)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != users.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!UsersExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: You will want to change your looping logic.  You are setting values on `$scope` for each item in `listeOfUsers`.  The end result is that `$scope` will have the values from the last entry in your list.  I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: @Jon, yes, but what to do to correct this problem

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an HTTP 405 because your controller method is set to accept `OPTIONS` requests, not `PUT` requests.

Comment: What to do to correct this problem, change request "OPTIONS" ?

Comment: Uncomment `// [HttpPut]` and remove `[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]`

Comment: I change my code, now it's the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998731/how-to-fix-probelm-of-update-users-in-asp-net-web-api?noredirect=1#comment87013552_49998731